# XQuery returning an error..?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, basex

Below is the XML file -

```
<Continents>
  <Continent n="Asia">
    <Country n="Thailand">
      <City>
        <Name>Bangkok</Name>
        <Desc>Capital on Thailand</Desc>
      </City>
    </Country>
    <Country n="India">
      <City>
        <Name>New Delhi</Name>
        <Desc>Capital on India</Desc>
      </City>
      <City>
        <Name>Mumbai</Name>
        <Desc>Financial capital on India</Desc>
      </City>
      <City>
        <Name>Chennai</Name>
        <Desc>A very good city</Desc>
      </City>
    </Country>
  </Continent>
</Continents>
```

Using baseX, I am writing a query to display the `Name` of cities containing the word **Capital** but is returning error. The query is -

```
/Continents/Continent[contains(Country/City/Desc,'Capital')]/Country/City/Name
```

and the error is -
**Error: [XPTY0004] Single item expected, (element Desc { ... }, element Desc { ... }, ...) found.**

Please help me out.. Is it required to use FLWOR for such queries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original query could have been rewritten as follows...

```
/Continents/Continent[
  some $x in Country/City/Desc satisfies contains($x,'Capital')]
  /Country/City/Name
```

...or...

```
/Continents/Continent[
  for $x in Country/City/Desc
  where contains($x,'Capital')
  return $x]/Country/City/Name
```

...but both of the queries will return *all* countries of *any* continent that contains a city description containing 'Capital'. Instead, this is probably what you are looking for:

```
/Continents/Continent/Country/City[contains(Desc,'Capital')]/Name
```

You may as well use the [contains text](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Full-Text)  expression to ignore case, diacritics, etc. in your key words:

```
/Continents/Continent/Country/City[Desc contains text 'Capital']/Name
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your predicate `[contains(Country/City/Desc,'Capital')]` selects all `Desc` nodes containing `'Capital'` for the `Continent` element, so it evaluates to three elements. To fix this, just move the predicate to the `City` element (after all, you want to filter the `City` elements, not the `Continent`). I didn't test it, but i would expect this to work:

```
/Continents/Continent/Country/City[contains(Desc,'Capital')]/Name
```