# How to get this output with XQuery?

Tags: xml, xquery, basex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XQuery returning an error..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314562/xquery-returning-an-error)

Below is the XML file -

```
<Continents>
  <Continent name="Asia">
    <Country name="Japan">
    <City name="Tokyo"><Desc>Tokoyo is a most populated City</Desc></City>
    <City name="Horishima"><Desc>What to say.. Faced the destruction due to Atom Bomb</Desc></City>
    </Country>
    <Country name="India">
    <City name="New Delhi"><Desc>Capital of India</Desc></City>
    <City name="Mumbai"><Desc>Financial Capital of India</Desc></City>
    <City name="Lucknow"><Desc>City of Nawabs</Desc></City>
    </Country>
  </Continent>  
</Continents>
```

I want to list Cities for Country=`"India"`

My XQuery FLWOR code is -

```
for $x in doc("Continent")/Continents/Continent
  where $x/Country/@name='India'
  return $x/Country/City/@name
```

I am wishing output as -

```
 name="New Delhi" name="Mumbai" name="Lucknow"
```

but getting output as -

```
 name="Tokyo" name="Horishima" name="New Delhi" name="Mumbai" name="Lucknow"
```

Can anybody help me to get correct output? Also how to get it on separate line?

Comment: This should already have been answered at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314562/xquery-returning-an-error

Comment: @Christian- Yes I shud have search first. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked almost the exact same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314562/xquery-returning-an-error) and the same answer applies here, too. What you want is:

```
doc("Continent")/Continents/Continent/Country[@name = 'India']/City/@name
```

If you want each result on its own line, try this:

```
string-join(
  doc("Continent")/Continents/Continent/Country[@name = 'India']/City/@name,
  '&#10;'
)
```

This should result in:

```
New Delhi
Mumbai
Lucknow
```

Comment: Yes I shud have search first. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Leo- Thanks the answer helped me to solve the same kinda problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could also rewrite your FLWOR a bit to get the wanted results:

```
for $x in doc("Continent")/Continents/Continent/Country
where $x/@name='India'
return $x/City/@name
```

(Note that I move the /Country part)

If necessary you can wrap this FLWOR in a string-join as suggested by Leo the same way he wraps his XPath expression alternative..

Answer (score 1):

```
/*/*/Country[@name='India']/City/concat('name="', @name, '" ')
```

**Note**: This also happens to be a pure XPath 2.0 expression.